# mysql join with multiple tables and count query

Tags: mysql

I have total 6 tables in which different info has been saved

Now i need a result in which get count from 5 tables and select all info from main table but if record does not exist than it must be need to return 0 instead of no row found that's the problem here

I have tried below query but didn't get success

```
SELECT 
    u.*,
    COUNT(DISTINCT  c.id) as comments,
    COUNT(DISTINCT d.id) as dislikes,
    COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) as likes,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) as shares,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) as tags
FROM 
    job_details as u
    JOIN job_comments as c ON u.id = c.job_id
    JOIN job_dislike as d ON u.id = d.job_id
    JOIN job_like as l ON u.id = l.job_id
    JOIN job_share as s ON u.id = s.job_id
    JOIN job_tags as t ON u.id = t.job_id
WHERE 
    u.id = c.job_id AND
    u.id = d.job_id AND
    u.id = l.job_id AND
    u.id = s.job_id AND
    u.id = t.job_id

GROUP BY 
    u.id
```

This query is executed, but didn't get exact result.
I don't quite understand why.

I was hoping somebody here could help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Post some sample data, actual and expected results.

Comment: Probably you get less data than you are expecting due to the fact you have INNER JOINS...you should check which is the main table and join the others with LEFT Join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't get the exact result because some tables may be missing values.

Although you can solve this problem with a `LEFT JOIN`, the safer solution is to pre-aggregate the data:

```
SELECT u.*, c.comments, d.dislikes, l.likes, s.shares, t.tags
FROM job_details as u LEFT JOIN
     (select c.job_id, count(*) as comments from job_comments group by c.job_id
     ) c
     ON u.id = c.job_id LEFT JOIN
     (select d.job_id, count(*) as dislikes from job_dislike d group by d.job_id
     ) d
     ON u.id = d.job_id LEFT JOIN
     (select l.job_id, count(*) as likes from job_like l group by l.job_id
     ) l
     ON u.id = l.job_id LEFT JOIN
     (select s.job_id, count(*) as shares from job_share s group by s.job_id
     ) s
     ON u.id = s.job_id LEFT JOIN
     (select t.job_id, count(*) as tags from job_tags t group by t.job_id
     ) t
     ON u.id = t.job_id;
```

Why is this better?  Consider an id that has 5 comments, likes, dislikes, shares and tags.  The `JOIN` approach produces an intermediate result with 5*5*5*5*5 = 3,125 intermediate rows.  Things can really get out of hand for popular ids.

Comment: is it possible to add where condition in this query ?

Comment: @AnkitDoshi . . . Yes . . . In the outer query or in the `on` clauses, depending on what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. and you don't need `WHERE` clause since you have joined those tables. And, use `IFNULL` function to return 0 for null values. You need to modify you query like this :

```
SELECT u.id,
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT  c.id),0) as comments,
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT d.id),0) as dislikes,
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT l.id),0) as likes,
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT s.id),0) as shares,
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT t.id),0) as tags
FROM job_details as u
    LEFT JOIN job_comments as c ON u.id = c.job_id
    LEFT JOIN job_dislike as d ON u.id = d.job_id
    LEFT JOIN job_like as l ON u.id = l.job_id
    LEFT JOIN job_share as s ON u.id = s.job_id
    LEFT JOIN job_tags as t ON u.id = t.job_id
GROUP BY u.id
```